# NoBean found exception

Tags: spring, antbuilder

**I am getting below error even though i have down the @autowired .please some one let me know why this issue happening its  a ant build with spring config
utor.
2022-07-08 10:18:09,856   WARN org.springframework.context.support.
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization

- cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
  Error creating bean with name 'delegateProcessor':
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'headerProcessor';
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
  No qualifying bean found for dependency
  [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor<com.abc.proj.model.FileHeader,
  com.abc.proj.model.FileHeader>]:
  expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
  Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=headerProcessor)}
  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
  Error creating bean with name 'delegateProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
  through field 'headerProcessor';
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.
  NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency
  [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor<com.abc.proj.model.FileHeader,
  com.abc.proj.model.FileHeader>]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
  autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
  {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=headerProcessor)}

---

```
@Component
public class DelegateProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Object, Object>, InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("headerProcessor")
    private ItemProcessor<FileHeader, FileHeader> headerProcessor;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("detailProcessor")
    private ItemProcessor<FileDetail, FileDetail> detailProcessor;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("trailerProcessor")
    private ItemProcessor<FileTrailer, FileTrailer> trailerProcessor;
```

---

```
@Component
public class HeaderProcessor implements  ItemProcessor<Object, Object>{
    @Autowired
    private HeaderValidatorDao headerValidatorDao ;**
```

Comment: You need to create manually instances of ItemProcessor with those names "headerProcessor", "detailProcessor", "trailerProcessor"

Comment: @CaptainPyscho can you please explain little more in detail on how to do it ..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With a configuration class you could initialize your beans manually, specially if they need custom names.

```
@Configuration
public class MyCustomConfiguration {
   
   @Bean(name ="headerProcessor")
   public ItemProcessor<FileHeader, FileHeader> headerProcessorBean() {
      ItemProcessor<FileHeader, FileHeader> myBean = new HeaderProcessor<>();
      //Do whaterever you need to initilize your bean
      return myBean;
   }

   @Bean(name ="detailProcessor")
   public ItemProcessor<FileDetail, FileDetail> detailProcessorBean() {
      ItemProcessor<FileDetail, FileDetail> myBean = new ItemProcessor<>();
      //Do whaterever you need to initilize your bean
      return myBean;
   }
}
```

In this way these beans will be available for autowiring.

Comment: You also don't have to explicitly declare the bean name. If the bean name is not specified, the bean name will be the method name.